# why default constructor is not present for a class containing const data members

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor

why default constructor is not added by the compiler for the class containing constant data members.
please see the below code , in that i have declared constant data member 'a' and while trying to create object for a class 'ClassA' it is saying No Appropriate Default constructor is available . please help.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ClassA
{
    private:
  const int a;
    public :
  void print()
  {
      cout << "hello world" << endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  ClassA obj;
  obj.print();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to initialize `a`.

Comment: Despite comments elsewhere, the obvious initialisation for `a` is with the default initialiser, namely `int()`, which will initialise with zero. Yes, this is (almost) pointless, but does anyone have a reference as to why it is not possible for the default constructor?

Comment: @Keith It is just a choice of the language. Built-in data members do not get initialized by default.

Comment: @juanchopanza. Of course. So why is the lack of initialisation  problem just because `a` is `const`?

Comment: This was solved in C#, by making the compiler force the developer to initialize `const` variables inline.

Comment: @Keith: because you cannot change the value of a `const` variable after the fact, so what good is it if it is not initialized to start with ? (knowing that reading an uninitialized value is undefined behavior)

Comment: @Keith What Matthieu M. said. But that is another language decision. It could have been allowed, but then you would end up with a data member with an undetermined value that cannot be changed. It is unlikely that this could be useful as it would easily lead to undefined behaviour (BTW I asked the same question a few years ago. It was a duplicate then, but I can't find it...)

Comment: @MatthieuM. Charles Bailey answers in terms of the standard; so case closed. However, I don't think failure of the constructor to initialize means `a` is uninitialized memory; could we not be overlaying known memory using in-place new?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a const value cannot change after it is initialized how could a default constructor choose a value for it. So the default constructor is not created

Answer (score 5):

The C++03 rule was specified in 12.6.2/4 [class.base.init]. If a non-static member of a class was not mentioned in the member initializer list of a constructor then if it was `const` qualified it would have to be of a non-POD class type with a user-declared constructor otherwise the program would be ill-formed. A implicitly defined constructor is defined with an empty member initializer list (and empty body) so, in this case, causing the implicitly declared default constructor to be implicitly defined it would also render the program ill-formed.

The C++11 rule amounts to the same thing. Non-static data members which are not specified in the member initializer list are *default initialized*. In C++11 8.5/6 [dcl.init], "[...] If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a const-qualified type `T`, `T` shall be a class type with a user-provided default constructor." which boils down to the same rule in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Since `a` is a `const` variable, you can declare it as static and initialize it, without using a constructor as follows,

```
class ClassA
{
    private:
    const static int a=10;
    public :
    void print()
    {
      cout << "hello world" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
  ClassA obj;
  obj.print();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The type `int` does not have a default value in C or C++, therefore the value of `a` would be undefined.  For example, VC++ will populate the value of `a` with a different default value if it is run in debug to if it is run in release mode.

In debug, VC++ [populates uninitialized memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Magic_debug_values) with the following values:

> - 0xCCCCCCCC - Used by Microsoft's C++ debugging runtime library and many DOS environments to mark uninitialized stack memory.
> - 0xCDCDCDCD - Used by Microsoft's C/C++ debug malloc() function to mark uninitialized heap memory, usually returned from HeapAlloc()

So by not initializing `a` your program will have a different const  value each time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to explicitly initialize const members in the constructor, you'd have to set them somewhere, and as they are const, you can just be setting it wherever you like!