# error with const member and default constructor

Tags: c++, default-constructor

I have two versions of a C++ code. One give the problem and other does not:

```
/*
 * This compiles fine
 */
class base {
    private:
         const char c;
    };

int main() {
    base b(); // compiles fine
}
```

/*
 * This gives compilation error
 */

```
class base {
    private:
         const char c;
    };

int main() {
    base b; // error: structure 'b' with uninitialized const members

}
```

Note the difference is 'base b()' and 'base b'.
I thought that both will call default constructor and since the class has a const field, the program will fail to compile.
Please help to explain this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why default constructor is not present for a class containing const data members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706674/why-default-constructor-is-not-present-for-a-class-containing-const-data-members)

Comment: You're another victim of C++'s "most vexing parse" (you can Google it): `base b();` is **not** parsed as a variable definition by the compiler, but as a _function declaration_ -- just like `int f();` or `void g();`. (Rule of thumb: anything the compiler _can_ interpret as a function declaration, it _will_.)

Answer (score 5):

That is because the first version does not create an object of type `base`, but rather **declares a function** called `b` which takes no argument and returns an object of type `base`:

```
base b; // Declares an object b of type base
base b(); // Declares a FUNCTION called b that takes no argument an returns a base
```

In fact, you could try the following to verify that this is indeed the case:

```
int main() {
    base b(); // DECLARES function b()
    b(); // INVOKES function b()
}

base b() // DEFINITION of function b()
{
    base c;
    // ...
    return c;
}
```

Now function `main()` won't give you problems anymore, but the `base c;` inside the `b()` function will. Exactly like the `base b;` in your original example. Why?

Well, because in general data members whose type is `const`-qualified should be initialized as soon as you construct the object (just like data members of a reference type). A way to guarantee this in general is to initialize those data members in the [**constructor's initialization list**](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html).

This, for instance, will compile:

```
class base {
public:
    base() : c('x') { }
private:
    const char c;
};

int main() {
    base b;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andy. You explained it well.

Answer (score 1):

const char c; Must be defined when declared.
const char c = 'a'; for example